# What is the name and definition of set based on permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, permutations, terminology

I have come across the question: [Combination of n sets that produces a set of $n$-tuple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161730/combination-of-n-sets-that-produces-a-set-of-n-tuple).

Given two ordered sets with $n=3$ elements: $A=\{2, 4, 6\}$, $B=\{1, 3, 5\}$, $a_i < b_i$, $i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.

**Question.** How to name and define the set based on combination of this sets that produces the set $C$ with $2^n$ elements ($n$-tuples) as following:
$$C=\left\{\\(1,3,5),\\
(1,3,6),\\(1,4,5),\\(1,4,6),\\(2,3,5),\\(2,3,6),\\(2,4,5),\\(2,4,6)\\\right\}.$$

**My attempt is:**

**Name**: $C$ is the set of ordered permutation without replacement of two $n$-elements sets $A$ and $B$.

**Update.**

**Definition:** $C=\{(x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n): x_i =a_i \vee b_i, i=1,2, \ldots, n\}=\{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_N\}$, where $N=2^n$.

I'm confused because in my definition because the sign $\vee$ denotes the logical `OR` there, but elements of $A$ and $B$ are integers.

I have read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Logical operators are typically used with Boolean (logical) values. When they are, they return a Boolean value. However, the && and || operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value.

Comment: May be $\lor$ means the least common multiple.

Comment: No, $\vee$ means OR, the value $c_i$ in each $n$-tuples equal to  selection between $a_i$ and $b_i$.

Comment: I think you mean $c_i = a_i \vee c_i = b_i$.  There will be $2^n$ choices since for each $i$ you have the choice of $a_i$ or $b_i$, assuming $a_i \neq b_i$.

Comment: @JairTaylor, I have update the question, $C$ looks like as a thust table of integers.